# Remove last character from regular expression match

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm working on an ansible playbook to copy some content between files.
To do that, I made a regular expression that match the content I want to copy.

I made a quick example with a var, just to test the regular expression.

```
- set_fact:
    the_var: >
            [Java,WBS]
            java    critical 1-
            *ARGS node_name server_name1
            [Java,WBS]
            java    critical 1-
            *ARGS node_name server_name2

- debug:
    msg: "{{the_var}}"

- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ the_var | regex_search('\\[[J|j]ava(.*)\\[', multiline=True)}}"

- name: Print
  debug:
    var: my_var
```

This is the output I get:

```
TASK [create_app : Print] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [test_server] => {
    "my_var": "[Java,WBS] \\ java    critical 1- *ARGS node_name server_name1 ["
}
```

How can I remove the last "**[**" from the output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the character, but not include it in the returned match.

```
my_var: "{{ the_var | regex_search('\\[[J|j]ava(.*)(?=\\[)', multiline=True)}}"
```

Comment: It worked perfect, thanks. I thought I tested, looks like I didn't do it correctly :)